# Find Maximum Value in Column Pandas

Tags: pandas, max

I have a data frame like this- Machine Vibration data.

|  | datetime | tagid | value | quality |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2021-03-01 13:43:41.440 | B42 | 345 | 192 |
| 1 | 2021-03-01 13:43:41.440 | B43 | 958 | 192 |
| 2 | 2021-03-01 13:43:41.440 | B44 | 993 | 192 |
| 3 | 2021-03-01 13:43:41.440 | B45 | 1224 | 192 |
| 4 | 2021-03-01 13:43:43.527 | B188 | 6665 | 192 |
| 5 | 2021-03-01 13:43:43.527 | B189 | 7162 | 192 |
| 6 | 2021-03-01 13:43:43.527 | B190 | 7193 | 192 |
| 7 | 2021-03-01 13:43:43.747 | C29 | 2975 | 192 |
| 8 | 2021-03-01 13:43:43.747 | C30 | 4445 | 192 |
| 9 | 2021-03-01 13:43:43.747 | C31 | 4015 | 192 |

I want to convert this to hourly maximum value for each tag id.

Sample Output

| datetime | tagid | value | quality |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-03-2021 13:00 | C91 | 3982 | 192 |
| 01-03-2021 14:00 | C91 | 3972 | 192 |
| 01-03-2021 13:00 | C92 | 9000 | 192 |
| 01-03-2021 14:00 | C92 | 9972 | 192 |
| 01-03-2021 13:00 | B42 | 396 | 192 |
| 01-03-2021 14:00 | B42 | 370 | 192 |
| 01-03-2021 15:00 | B42 | 370 | 192 |

I tried with grouper, but couldn't get output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) with aggregate `max`:

```
df = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='H', key='datetime'), 'tagid']).max().reset_index()
```